# Layout items on QToolBox page to expand with page

Tags: qt, layout, qt-designer, qtoolbox

In Qt Designer, how do you lay out the items on the pages of a QToolBox so that they expand with the toolbox? I have tried adding a table-view widget on a QToolBox page. Please see image:

[image]

But when the QToolBox is expanded along with my application main window, the table-view does not expand with the toolbox page.

Is there something I am missing ?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, first I **had to have a layout on the desired page** of the toolbox.

Then I had to **highlight the toolbox itself** in the object inspector pane (while the page I want to layout on is active AND has a layout object !!).

Then I chose the desired layout from the toolbox context menu (i.e. right mouse click on the toolbox object and choose Layout). This changed the layout on the active page. Not sure why this worked but it worked.

Thanks @ekhumoro for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on the toolbox page to select it, and then set a layout on the page itself. Each page in the toolbox will need its own layout set in this way.

If you look in the Object Inspector, you will see that each page has a QWidget automatically added to it. The layout for each toolbox page is actually set on that container widget, which then holds whatever other widgets you add to the page. Once the layout has been set properly, you should see the icon in the Object Inspector change to the appropriate layout icon.